# Matlab, Ubuntu: preview and local scope not accessible while debugging nested scripts

Tags: matlab, debugging, ubuntu, preview, workspace

everyone!

I am running Matlab R2016a on my Ubuntu 14.04.
I have a main script that calls some user-coded functions. As long as I debug the main script, the preview of the variables while hovering on them works fine and the variables shown in the workspace are accessible as usual.
As soon as I start debugging the nested functions, none of the previous aids work. The preview doesn't show up and the workspace is not updated with the local variables. Also, if I try to open any of the variables with the variable editor, the editor opens but it doesn't show anything.

Does anybody have a clue?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured it out.

In the function script that I wanted to debug there were definitions of multiple functions. By placing each definition in a separate file the debugger works as fine as usual.
I guess that Matlab is not capable of debugging scripts with multiple function definitions because it becomes impossible to distinguish (or represent) the different scopes in one window, especially if the local variables have the same name.

Thanks anyway!

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. MATLAB is absolutely capable of doing this. I highly recommend [submitting a bug report](https://www.mathworks.com/support/bugreports/) so they can fix the issue rather than writing this off completely as something MATLAB "isn't capable" of doing.